# NodeJS/Mongo Retrieve relational data on collection lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a very simple calendar/booking system that I'm building. A `calendar` entry refers to a given date, with a `maxAppointments` value. Anytime a booking is made, an entry is added to the `bookings` table with the given number of appointments (a `calendar` entry can have many `booking` entries).

// calendarModel.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

var CalendarSchema = new Schema({
  startDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  maxAppointments: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Max Appointments Required'
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Calendar', CalendarSchema)
```

// calendarController.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose' 
import moment from 'moment'
const Calendar = mongoose.model('Calendar')

// FIXME: listCalendar needs to return the number of currently available slots
export const listCalendar = (req, res) => {
  let now = moment().toDate()
  Calendar.find({startDate : { $gte : now }}, (err, calendar) => { 
    if (err)
      res.send(err)
    res.json(calendar)
  })
}
```

// bookingModel.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

var BookingSchema = new Schema({
  calendarId: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Calendar ID Required'
  },
  appointments: {
    type: Number
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bookings', BookingSchema)
```

Once payment is complete, an entry is added to the `booking` collection with the `calendarId` and the number of appointments that this booking has. The question that I have is how to adjust listCalendar to return the number of `availableAppointments` (which is `calendar.maxpAppointments` - `the sum of all appointments where booking.calendarId==selectedCalendarId`)

I currently see two options:

1. Anytime a `calendar` entry is retrieved, also retrieve the sum of `booking.appointments` (this would be calculated on the fly).
2. Add a field titled `bookedAppointments` to `calendarModel` and add/subtract to this field anytime a booking is made.

What's the best way to handle this, and there is the best place to put this logic? If I take route #1, should I add this logic to `listCalendar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route #1 calculates `availableAppointments` on the fly (with MongoDb Aggregation)

```
Calendar.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      startDate: {
        $gte: now
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Bookings",
      let: {
        id: {
          $toString: "$_id"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$calendarId",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "availableAppointments"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      availableAppointments: {
        $subtract: [
          "$maxAppointments",
          {
            $sum: "$availableAppointments.appointments"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
], (err, calendar) => { 
    if (err)
        res.send(err)
    res.json(calendar);
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PCmBIyf-IsW)

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. I've (slightly) modified your MongoPlayground to include additional fields (`title` and `notes`) in the Calendar collection: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wrXj5QQhNaL - How can I retrieve all of the fields from the `Calendar` collection (but NOT include any of the `booking` fields, except `availableAppointments`, without specify every field in the model in the `$project` object? I essentially just want the content from the Calendar collection with `availableAppointments`

Comment: Also, how can I only return `Calendar` entries where `availableAppointments > 0`?

Comment: @execv question #1: can you post desired result, so I can see what do you need. Question #2: you need to add extra `$match` at the end like this: `{$match:{"availableAppointments":{$gt:0}}}`

Comment: Thank you! To illustrate this I've added a few more fields to the `Calendar` collection (https://mongoplayground.net/p/6wXCGvGyKpE). An example of the desired result is here: https://pastebin.com/VgjhQN5i - just the `Calendar` collection with the added `availableAppointments` fields (without needing to specify every field in the collection in the $project section). I tried changing the `project` to an `addFields` option, which works as expected, but it includes the `booking` object as well (which contains information on the bookings made, which I do not want to include).